# Boostrap 4 Navbar Dropdown in Angular not working on small devices

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular7, navbar

I added a collapsed navbar to my Angular 7 project, but when I push the button, it is not showing the menu items. I have tried changing the style. Adding other components and add the navbar to the components. Even tried restartring my computer to see if it will change but nothing gave results

[image: Image of my non-working navbar]

in styles.scss
 `@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";`

in package.json

`"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }`

in app.component.ts

`````
<header>
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <h1>
        Welcome to CV!
      </h1>
    </div>
  </header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav2">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="nav2">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Index</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>````
`````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is that when you add the jquery and bootstrap as scripts in the index.html, the functionality of the button is brought back

````
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>```
````